# Difficult Integration by Substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Using a suitable substitution, find

$$\int \frac{x \sin x \cos x}{(x-\sin x \cos x)^2}dx.$$

I'm really struggling to find a substitution that will help me even get started.

Comment: Close vote is undue in my opinion,

Comment: Looks like you assumed that something like $\frac{c}{a+b}$ could be written as $\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}$.  It cannot. Example,  $\frac{1}{2+3}$  does not equal $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: True - I've edited it now - thanks!

Comment: Note with your incorrect attempt, you could have continued it by knowing that $\sin(x) \cos(x)=\frac12\sin2x$. Ultimately that answer is wrong, but just so you know how to tackle that sort of integral in future. I believe that rule will also be a massive help here anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can rewrite the integrand as
$$ \frac{x\sec^2{x}\tan{x}}{(x\sec^2{x}-\tan{x})^2} $$
by dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos^4{x}$. Now try putting $ u=x\sec^2{x}-\tan{x} $, so $du = 2x\sec^2{x}\tan{x}+\sec^2{x} - \sec^2{x} = 2x\sec^2{x}\tan{x} $. Hence the integral becomes $ \frac{1}{2} \int du/u^2$.

Comment: And no, I have no intuition for why this is the "right" thing to do: I just went looking for ways to change the denominator so the inside of the bracket had a derivative consisting of a single term.